# Vite Dynamic Import with new Url not working in SSR

Tags: server-side-rendering, vite, nuxt3

I've a Nuxt 3 component which has a background image property passed from the parent.

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['image'])
</script>
```

The image property is not fetched via an api call during runtime. It is known during build time.

I'm however not able to load the image using Vite.

When using something like

```
const imageUrl = new URL(`/assets/images/${props.image}`, import.meta.url).pathname
```

It is working on client side but not on server side (SSR) which is also stated in the Vite docs and expected.

However, using a dynamic imports like

```
const ogImage = await import(`./assets/images/${props.image}`)
```

I get a `The above dynamic import cannot be analyzed by Vite.`

I can't believe that there is no simple way to load assets via a variable which is know at build time. Webpacks `require()` statements worked flawlessly for this.